# Is it possible to have HTML content in Gmail.Draft's update method? (body: String)

Tags: gmail-api

Is  it possible to have HTML content in Gmail.Draft's update method?

In `Gmail.Draft`'s update method, having retrieved a Draft email, like:

`var draft = GmaailApp.getDrafts()[0];`

Updating works for plain text:
`draft.update(recipients, subject, "New text for the draft");`

But ***is it possible to replace the Body
content with HTML content?*** (the Body parameter is String)

`draft.update(recipients, subject, "<b>New text</b> for the draft");  // doesn't work`

Comment: What is so wrong with this question that someone would vote to close it?? If you vote to close a post at least have the decency to comment on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set HTML body, you have to use the advanced parameter `htmlBody`:

```
const options = {
  htmlBody: "<b>New text</b> for the draft"
}
draft.update(recipients, subject, "", options)
```

If you provide that parameter, the `body` parameter is ignored.

#### Reference:

- [GmailDraft.update(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft#update(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time to share your knowledge. This has been giving me a headache for weeks. I'll be using it as a workaround for createDraftReplyAll not working as expected (wrong recipient/cc), by creating a draft reply to a specific thread with createDraftReplyAll then correcting the recipient with this update method (with the same Subject and the required HTML, from a template). That hack now works! Faith in humanity restored.